# Json File For Chrome Theme Invalid

Tags: json, google-chrome, syntax

I am trying to create a Chrome theme for school. I looked and the Google developer site for theme (http://developer.google.com/extensions/themes), and there was an example code that I copied to see if it worked. I changed the name and the images it referenced to test it out, and when I uploaded the unpacked extension it gave the error code "Invalid Syntax". My code is below:

```
{
 "version": "2.6",
 "name”: “aaron speed“,
 “manifest_version”: “2”, 
 "theme": {
     "images" : {
       "theme_frame" : "images/main_wallpaper.png”,
       "theme_frame_overlay" : "images/main_wallpaper.png",
       "theme_toolbar" : "images/theme_toolbar_camo.png",
       "theme_ntp_background" : "images/main_wallpaper.png”,
       "theme_ntp_attribution" : "images/main_wallpaper.png"
     },
     "colors" : {
       "frame" : [71, 105, 91],
       "toolbar" : [207, 221, 192],
       "ntp_text" : [20, 40, 0],
       "ntp_link" : [36, 70, 0],
       "ntp_section" : [207, 221, 192],
       "button_background" : [255, 255, 255]
     },
     "tints" : {
       "buttons" : [0.33, 0.5, 0.47]
     },
     "properties" : {
       "ntp_background_alignment" : "bottom"
     }  
   }
 }
```

Edit: I don't have enough rep to post images, here is the error message: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmPUL.png

Comment: What do you mean? (Sorry I am not good at coding.)

Comment: My bad you have the correct muber of ``{`` and ``}``, however you may have an issue with you quotes. ``”`` is not ``"``. Try to replace all ``”`` with ``"``.

Comment: "number" not "muber"... anyway check my answer :-) Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace all `“` and `”` with `"` as follows:

```
{
 "version": "2.6",
 "name": "aaron speed",
 "manifest_version": "2", 
 "theme": {
     "images" : {
       "theme_frame" : "images/main_wallpaper.png",
       "theme_frame_overlay" : "images/main_wallpaper.png",
       "theme_toolbar" : "images/theme_toolbar_camo.png",
       "theme_ntp_background" : "images/main_wallpaper.png",
       "theme_ntp_attribution" : "images/main_wallpaper.png"
     },
     "colors" : {
       "frame" : [71, 105, 91],
       "toolbar" : [207, 221, 192],
       "ntp_text" : [20, 40, 0],
       "ntp_link" : [36, 70, 0],
       "ntp_section" : [207, 221, 192],
       "button_background" : [255, 255, 255]
     },
     "tints" : {
       "buttons" : [0.33, 0.5, 0.47]
     },
     "properties" : {
       "ntp_background_alignment" : "bottom"
     }  
   }
 }
```

These are different characters. I don't know what editor you're using in order to edit your code, but it looks to me that you're using word or wordpad or something similar...

Comment: Yeah, I use Textedit on Mac. Thanks for the help! It worked well.